Is "Just Works" allowed in BLE Secure Connections Only Mode (Mode 1 Level 4)?
Assuming the pairing request from central to peripheral looks like this:

Then the pairining would use Secure Connection, but with the Authentication Method "Just Works" because of the IO-Capabilites of the initiating device.
My question is: Can this connection still be considered Mode 1 Level 4 aka. SCO?

"Just Works" always means unauthenticated, so the maximum level is 2. You are talking about this, right?

Yes exactly that. So if I'm talking about a connection between a wireless keyboard and its dongle, then one could not consider it implementing "secure connections only mode", if the keyboard would accept such a pairing request, where no authentication is required, is that correct?

I don't think yours is a good example. Such a combination could be paired and bonded by the manufacturer at the factory and then a connection could be considered secure. I'm not sure what you're getting at.

I know what you mean, but assuming it is a model that allows unpairing and repairing and even pairing multiple devices to a single USB-Dongel, like Logitech Unifying Protocol did. Do you think the keyboard should be able to accept a pairing request as descirbe and still be in Secure Connections Only Mode?

Let me rephrase my question: Does "Just Works" count as "authenticated Pairing" when both sides set the MitM flag? In the specifications it says: "Authenticated pairing involves performing the pairing procedure defined in [Vol 3] Part H, Section 2.1 with the authentication set to ‘MITM protection’. Unauthenticated pairing involves performing the pairing procedure with authentication set to ‘No MITM protection’."

Found the answer:
According to this table, when at least one device has the MitM-bit set, neither of them has the OOB bit set and the initiating device has NoInputNoOutput as its IO-capabilites, then JustWorks Unauthenticated will be used. This means, that it is not an authenticated pairing, therefore it does not fulfilll the requirements for being mode 1 level 4 and the state of being can not be called "Secure Connections Only Mode"
